# How to avoid errors when uploading multiple files?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a file input which is an array but what I had previously no longer works, it seems to throw an error for multiple files, it just uploads the latest file. I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="userfile" class="multi" />
```

Then in my controller:

```
$upload_files = $_FILES;
var_dump($upload_files['userfile']['name']);
// get the selected files out of the array
for($i = 0; $i < count($upload_files['userfile']['name']); $i++) {
   $_FILES['userfile'] = array(
      'name' => $upload_files['userfile']['name'][$i],
      'type' => $upload_files['userfile']['type'][$i],
      'tmp_name' => $upload_files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],
      'error' => $upload_files['userfile']['error'][$i],
      'size' => $upload_files['userfile']['size'][$i]
);
```

Comment: I believe the array of files wil be `$_FILES['userfile']` not `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`

Comment: So in your case: `$upload_files['userfile']`

Comment: try this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19606/Javascript-PHP-Multiple-File-Upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `$_FILES['userfile']` on each iteration of the array (which is why only the last file is uploaded).

Create a new array element each time it loops.

Also, change your loop to iterate over `$upload_files['userfile']` instead of `$upload_files['userfile']['name']` as suggested in the above comments :)

---

Just a pointer - it is better to assign `count($upload_files['userfile'])` to a variable outside of your `for` loop. It probably won't make much difference if your array only has a few elements, but has massive performance benefits when working with large arrays.

Check out http://www.phpbench.com/

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the array at each iteration, try something like:

> ```
> foreach($upload_files['userfile'] as $i => $file) {
>    $_FILES['userfile_org'][$i] = array(
>       'name' => $file['name'],
>       'type' => $file['type'],
>       'tmp_name' => $file['tmp_name'],
>       'error' => $file['error'],
>       'size' => $file['size']
>    ); 
>   } 
>   echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_FILES['userfile_org']); die;
> ```

Comment: what is the difference between your  ans and deifud ans ?

Comment: Only difference is that I have the sample solution. While stood had not seen his response :(